# Redirecting page changes image request resulting in 404 not found in Next.Js

Tags: next.js

I have a page called customers in next.Js and another page [id], so it generates the routes `/customers` and `/customers/id`.

I wanted to map a list of customers in `/customers` and if I click on a customer in that list I will be redirected to `/customers/id` with the information of the customers, this logic is working very well, the problem is when I leave the `/customers/id` page, for some reason it messes up with some images in my other pages.

I have 2 examples:

example 1: when I try to back to customers page from customers/id it doesn't find my background image from that page, but if I refresh the page it renders normally with the background image.

Example 2: I have a function to validate jwt tokens in a hook and if this token is expired it redirects to the login page, when it does that redirect from `customers/id` page it doesn't find the background and icon images, but again, if I refresh the page it renders normally, trying to understand that problem I open the console in chrome and realized that when I am redirected from `customers/id` it changes the request url of the images, all my images are located in `public/img`, so in my imgs tag I just put '/imagename.jpg' in source, with that all my requests to that images should be "http://localhost:3000/img/imagename.jpg", but with the `customers/id` redirect that request transforms into "http://localhost:3000/customers/img/imagename.jpg", and for that reason I get the 404 code.

Can someone help me with this issue? Thank you guys for the attention.

Comment: Thank you, I already made it, thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - I just forgot to put /img in my source, it was `img/imgname` and I just changed to `/img/imgname`